# Choosing right scale for global aggregations in GEE

Tags: coordinate-system, google-earth-engine, scale

What is a correct scale to aggregate global datasets like [VIIRS Nighttime Lights](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/NOAA_VIIRS_DNB_MONTHLY_V1_VCMCFG#description) in GEE, a scale that will retain maximum (original) amount of information when aggregating over any place in the world (any latitude)?

For example, VIIRS Nighttime Day/Night Band Composites [have resolution of 15 arc seconds](https://eogdata.mines.edu/products/vnl/), which corresponds to ~500 m at the Equator but up to [~320 m in high latitudes](https://www.esri.com/news/arcuser/0400/wdside.html). Does it mean that setting `scale: 500` will keep original amount of information everywhere?

```
result = VIIRScoll.reduceRegions({
  collection: areasInAnyLatitudes, 
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(), 
  scale: 500, // ~15 arc sec on equator but ~9 arc sec in 49 degrees north latitude.
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the projection and resolution of the original images, rather than picking your own (but make sure you understand what that is, so you're not surprised):

```
print(VIIRScoll.first().projection().nominalScale())
result = VIIRScoll.reduceRegions({
  collection: areasInAnyLatitudes, 
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(), 
  crs: VIIRScoll.first().projection()
})
```